# with-eval-after-load and order of evaluation in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Given the situation below:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'python
  exp1
  )

(with-eval-after-load 'python
  exp2
  )
```

Is `exp2` guaranteed to be evaluated after `exp1` when python mode is loaded?

How about if those two `with-eval-after-load` are in different files, and `file2` containing `exp2` requires `file1` containing `exp1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that they are evaluated in the same order in which the `eval-after-load` forms are evaluated.

If each `eval-after-load` is evaluated only once, then that's all you need to know. Otherwise some additional detail may be of interest...

If `'python` has not yet been `provide`d then the order in which `exp1` and `exp2` will be evaluated is (again) strictly the order in which their enclosing `eval-after-load` forms are evaluated; but more specifically, it is the order in which they are *first* evaluated. If either of those `eval-after-load` forms were evaluated *multiple* times (but still prior to the library in question being loaded), that fact would have no effect on the eventual evaluations of `exp1` and `exp2` -- each of which would be evaluated once, and in that order.

If `'python` *has* been `provide`d already, then the behaviour is different: instead of deferred evaluation, the child expression is evaluated *immediately* (i.e. the form is effectively equivalent to `progn`), which means that should any of the `eval-after-load` forms be evaluated multiple times, their child forms will also be evaluated multiple times.

> How about if those two `with-eval-after-load` are in different files, and `file2` containing `exp2` requires `file1` containing `exp1`?

If `file2` is loaded first, and `file2` *loads* `file1`, then it depends on whether the `eval-after-load` in `file2` happens *before* it loads `file1` (in which case `exp2` happens first), or *after* it loads `file1` (in which case `exp1` happens first).

One minor curiosity in all of this is that the location of the `provide` expression in a library does not seem to affect matters. For the purposes of `eval-after-load`, things seem to work as if the `provide` were always at the very end of the library (as indeed it usually is), even if that isn't actually true. I suppose this ensures consistency between using a feature symbol or a library name as the `eval-after-load` argument, but I'm unsure of the details of why it works that way (because a cursory look at the code for `provide` suggests that it can directly invoke the `after-load` functionality).

n.b. `with-eval-after-load` is defined in terms of `eval-after-load`, which is why I have used the latter in this answer. The answer applies equally, regardless of which you use.

And in case it makes a difference, I am presently using Emacs 24.5.1.